# matplotlib not printing dates on x axes

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to print the upper, middle and lower bollinger bands of a stock in matplotlib. I have all the data in a pandas Dataframe. I converted the "date" column to a datetime and then a matplotlibdate. I use the following code.

```
import datetime as dt
import talib
from talib import MA_Type
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from util import toDateTime
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
date = pd.to_datetime(data['Date'])  #datetime type
dates = mdates.date2num(date) #float
y = data['Close'].values #array of stock price values
y1, y2, y3 = talib.BBANDS(y, matype=MA_Type.T3) ##Bollinger bands analysis
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%m/%d/%Y')) #prettify the labels
plt.plot(dates,y) #plot the dates on x an prices on y
plt.plot(dates,y1) #bollinger band high
plt.plot(dates,y2) #bollinger band middle
plt.plot(dates,y3) #bollinger band low
plt.show
```

CSV file of the data can be found here: http://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=TSLA+Historical+Prices

Anybody knows what I am missing?

Comment: skip the conversion from datatime. matplotlib can natively plot datatime objects.

Comment: Hi M4rtini thnx for your advice but it is not working. Though I do have a new issue: "x and y must have same first dimension". The arrays are both of the same size.

Comment: make sure they are the same shape ((N,) vs (N, 1) vs (1, N)).   Try explicitly getting numpy arrays out of pandas before plotting.

Comment: @tcaswell both of the arrays are of size (923,). I now have 2 arrays with the following properties:

<type 'numpy.ndarray'> (923,) <type 'numpy.datetime64'>
<type 'numpy.ndarray'> (923,) <type 'numpy.float64'>